# C-Programming. Error in code that won't let me go to next function

Tags: c, project

The following code is a project I'm working on and after entering the details as in name and email it won't go to the next part of the code which is printing the price and then go to the next function. What did I do wrong??

Also, what can I do so that a customer can enter their details with spacing?
Thanks in advance.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int option,card_num,csc,phone_number;
    char name,address,e_mail,registration;
    void membership();
    void payment();
    int main()
    {

    membership();

    return 0;

    }
    void membership()
    {
    printf("\tTHE CRUMP'S MEMBERSHIP");
    printf("\n\n This membership ...");
    printf("\n\n REGISTRATION [CONTRACTOR(A)/CORPORATION(B)]=");
    scanf("%c",&registration);
    switch (registration)
    {
    case 'A':
     printf("\n\nEnter details without any spacing.");
     printf("\nNAME:");
     scanf("%s",&name);
     printf("\nADDRESS:");
     scanf("%s",&address);
     printf("\nPHONE NUMBER:");
     scanf("%d",&phone_number);
     printf("\nE-MAIL:");
     scanf("%s",&e_mail);
     break;

    case 'B':
     printf("Enter details without any spacing.");
     printf("\nNAME OF CORPORATION:");
     scanf("%s",&name);
     printf("\nADDRESS OF CORPORATION:");
     scanf("%s",&address);
     printf("\nPHONE NUMBER OF CORPORATION:");
     scanf("%d",&phone_number);
     printf("\nE-MAIL OF CORPORATION:");
     scanf("%s",&e_mail);
     break;
     }

     if (registration=='A')
     printf("\n THE REGISTRATION FEE = |RM 50/MONTH |\t| RM 500/YEAR|");
     else if (registration=='B')
     printf("\n THE REGISTRATION FEE = |RM 200/MONTH |\t| RM 2200/YEAR|");
     }
     void payment()
     {
     printf("\n\nChoose method of payment: ");
     printf("\n\t 1- Money Transfer \n\t 2-Debit Card\n");
     scanf("%d",&option);

     if (option==1)
     {
     printf("\nYou have chosen Money Transfer.");
     printf("\nYou can transfer your money at our bank account --> 4365 4200 1471");
     printf ("\n your membership will be confirmed when we have received the payment");
     printf("\n************************************************************");
     if (registration=='A')
     {
     printf("\nNAME:%s",name);
     printf("\nADDRESS:%s",address);
     printf("\nPHONE NUMBER:%d",phone_number);
     printf("\nE-MAIL:%s",e_mail);
     }
     else if (registration=='B')
     {
     printf("\nNAME OF CORPORATION:%s",name);
     printf("\nADDRESS OF CORPORATION:%s",address);
     printf("\nPHONE NUMBER OF CORPORATION:%d",phone_number);
     printf("\nE-MAIL OF CORPORATION:%s",e_mail);
     }

     printf("\n\n your transaction completed...\n\n Enjoy your membership discount.");
     }
     else if (option==2)
     {
     printf("\nYou have chosen Credit/Debit card.");
     printf("\n Please enter your Credit/Debit card number:");
     scanf("%d",&card_num);
     printf("\n Please enter CSC code:");
     scanf("%d",&csc);
     printf("\nYour  membership will be confirmed when we have received the payment");
     printf("\n*********************************************************\n\n");

     if (registration=='A')
     {
     printf("\nNAME:%s",name);
     printf("\nADDRESS:%s",address);
     printf("\nPHONE NUMBER:%d",phone_number);
     printf("\nE-MAIL:%s",e_mail);
     }
     else if (registration=='B')
     {
     printf("\nNAME OF CORPORATION:%s",name);
     printf("\nADDRESS OF CORPORATION:%s",address);
     printf("\nPHONE NUMBER OF CORPORATION:%d",phone_number);
     printf("\nE-MAIL OF CORPORATION:%s",e_mail);
     }

     printf("\n\n Your transaction is completed...\n\n Enjoy your membership discount.");
     }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read strings into `char` variables:

```
char name,address,e_mail,registration;
//...
scanf("%s",&name);
```

`char` only holds one character, not a string. If you want to read a string use an character array:

```
char name[100];
//...
```

and pass it to `scanf` like this:

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

because the array already decays to a pointer and taking the address is unnecessary.

Note that this requires you to set a limit for the name length. For example I choose `100-1 = 99` characters as limit. If the input is longer, undefined behaviour occurs, which is what you are experiencing right now.

Also note that you never call `payment`, so this will never be executed. If you want it to be executed after `membership`, then you need to call it:

```
int main()
{

membership();
payment();

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has no call to payment() function thats why the program flow is not complete.